# Issue in showing next privilege on mobile version

Tags: bug, profile-page, next-privilege

Today I've noticed small issue in SO mobile version, here's the screenshot from desktop version:

[image]

And here's the mobile version with mistaken next privilege:

[image]

My current reputation is 2,392 and correct value for next privilege should be "2.5k Rep.", not "3k Rep". 3k Rep is [another privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions), not my next.

Comment: So what's the bug here? Is it the fact that one says "2,500 Rep." and the other says "3k Rep."?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist exactly. Correct value is "2,500 Rep.", not "3k Rep". 3k Rep is [another privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions), not my next.

Comment: I think it's just a rounding issue. I've noticed similar things accessing site from a phone.