# Bug: Next privilege "Create new tags"

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, next-privilege

I noticed a bug on the user profile about "Next privilege: Create new tags".

When I open my user profile in firefox on my desktop PC I see that my next privilege is "create new tags" at 1,5k rep (same value as on the privilege overview page). When I click on the progress bar a popup with "learn more about this privilege" shows up.

When I opened my user profile on my iphone6 safari browser when I click on the bar nothing happens. But this not the reason why I made this post. On mobile phone the privilege is shown at 2k rep instead of 1,5.

This is of my 
[**mobile**](http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150627/djpdck5o.jpg)
[image: mobileview]

And this is of my desktop:
[image: Desktopview]

Comment: because I don't see any option to do this on my mobile. rhere are no formatting "buttons" like when I open the page on my desktop where I see these tools for bold, italic, list, links and so on. Feel free to edit my post and to insert an SO uploaded image there.

Comment: There is a smaller display area on a mobile, so 1,500 gets rounded up to 2.

Comment: I wanted to report this bug as well, back then when I noticed it, but thought of it as being too minor and something that’s probably not worth fixing. But fortunately, now someone reported it. Although, I think it applies to all SE sites and should be on meta.SE.

Comment: if this is not a bug by itself and the reason is just what @DavidPostill  explained I think it would be better to show it as 1,5K - so without rounding up that much

Comment: This problem [was](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291202/issue-in-showing-next-privilege-on-mobile-version?rq=1) [reported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258990/amount-of-rep-for-next-privilege-varies) before and the answer was always the same - rounding issue.

Comment: @DavidPostill: Of course. There are not enough blank pixels between "Next privilege" and the needed reputation as we can see in  the screenshot.

Comment: @Qiu doesn't mean the rounding issue cannot be fixed.

Comment: @Qiu Ah on meta.SE that's why I didn't find it via search. I'm only active on SO (and a bit on sqa). Feel free to flag mine as duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fair enough - at least in this spot, there is enough space that we do not need to round quite as much as it currently is.

With you in the next build.

Comment: Am I right that the build is live? Looks fixed.

Comment: @bish - yeah, that's been live for days now (we normally build up to a few times a day during working days).